# I want to make laravel api for multiple file upload when i am uploading files in db it shows [] in db

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, laravel

I am making laravel api to upload multiple file upload in database but files are uploaded to databse please check the following code and help to detect problem where i am doing wrong. Here is my code below:
Here is my controller code:
    public function Images(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            //'user_id' => 'required',
            'title' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required',
            'image.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg',
        ]);

```
    if($validator->fails())

    {

    return $this->sendError($validator->errors()->first());  

    }
     $data = [];

     if($request->hasfile('image'))
     {


             foreach($request->file('image') as $key=>$file)
        {
            $data =  array();
            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);  
             $data[$key] = $name;
             //dd($data);
        }
     }

        $user = Auth::user();

        $user_image = new Image();

        $user_image->user_id = $user->id;

        $user_image->title = $request->title;

        $user_image->image = json_encode($data);


        $user_image->save();


    return $this->responseOk("Image Added Successfully.", $user_image);



}
```

output on testing through postman:

```
{
    "result": "Success",
    "message": "Image Added Successfully.",
    "data": {
        "user_id": 79,
        "title": "potofolio",
        "image": "[]",
        "updated_at": "2019-04-08 05:45:07",
        "created_at": "2019-04-08 05:45:07",
        "id": 17
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in your problem here?

Comment: images are not upload in databse please check my code where i am wrong

Comment: How did you set up the image column in your DB?